# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when looking at an array with no index

Tags: arrays, angular, chart.js

Just a thanks in advance for any help and for the tremendous resource this place has been before now.  This is my first time asking a question and I'm still a bit of a newbie so please forgive anything obvious that I'm missing.

I have a created an API out of an Postgresql database using node.  That is working fine my queries.js file is below.

```js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'user',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'database',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
});

const tableThree = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM t3_0 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }

  module.exports = {
    tableThree,
  }
```

This gets passed along to my index.js file....

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./queries')
const port = 3001

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
});

app.get('/table3', db.tableThree);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
});
```

which creates an api where I can view the information from my postgresql database.

From my angular project I import it as a service...

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class simulatorService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    
  }

  tableThree() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3001/table3")
      .pipe(map(result => result));
  }

}
```

I updated my app.module.ts file so the service could be used...

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { simulatorService } from './esim06.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [simulatorService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

then in the app.components.ts file I bring in the service and I am able to see the expected data.

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { simulatorService } from './esim06.service';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  chart = [];
  
  constructor(private simulator: simulatorService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.simulator.tableThree()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)

        //let i13 = res['list'] || [].map(res => res.i13);
        //let alldates = res['list'] || [].map(res => res.i2)

        let i13 = res[''].map(res => res.i13);
        let alldates = res[''].map(res => res.i2)

        let dates = []
        alldates.forEach((res) => {
            let jsdate = new Date(res)
            dates.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }))
        })
        console.log(dates)
        console.log(i13)

        this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: alldates,
            datasets: [
              {
                data: i13,
                borderColor: '#3cba9f',
                fill: false
              },
              //{
              //  data: acquireSun,
              //  borderColor: '#3cba9f',
              //  fill: false
              //},
            ]
          },
          options: {
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                display: true
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                display: true
              }]
            }
          }
        })
      });
  }

}
```

For the first console.log(res) I can view the data in the inspector....

```html
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "4097", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:38.728Z", ple_id: "177550", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
1: {id: "4094", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:31.710Z", ple_id: "177422", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
2: {id: "4095", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:30.923Z", ple_id: "177404", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
3: {id: "4096", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:28.333Z", ple_id: "177360", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
4: {id: "4093", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:25.074Z", ple_id: "177292", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
5: {id: "4090", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:22.743Z", ple_id: "177248", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
6: {id: "4091", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:21.822Z", ple_id: "177230", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
7: {id: "4092", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:19.356Z", ple_id: "177186", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
8: {id: "4088", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:16.093Z", ple_id: "177118", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
9: {id: "4089", time: "2019-03-16T04:06:13.648Z", ple_id: "177074", meta_id: "1", reduced_id: null, …}
length: 10
```

However, when I attempt to reference specific parts of the array through statements such as..

let i13 = res[''].map(res => res.i13);
let alldates = res[''].map(res => res.i2);

I get the following error..

```html
core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:25)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:194)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:132)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
```

I believe this is happening because the name of the array is undefined.  so I cant write something like..

let i13 = res['list'].map(res => res.i13);

but I don't know how to either force it to accept it as undefined or give the array an index.  Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little unclear on your goal, but res[''] or res['list'] definitely wont work. based on the console.log, res is an array. So you can call res.map on it, or you can use integers like res[3] to get a specific element. But you can't access it by string

Comment: You are absolutely right.  My problem is that there is no "variable" that I can call in the brackets.  I've tried res[] but then I just get the error error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.  the index for the array appears to be undefined so i can't tell it which variable in the array I want it to look at as I can't specify the array.  Does that help any.  I'm probebly not expressing it well.

Comment: Hmm, what if you try res[0], does that help you?

Comment: Unfortunetly no.  If I do that I get TypeError: res[0].map is not a function as an error.  I think I need to assign an index to the array somewhere, but I can't find out where it would need to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to throw out an answer based on our comment discussion, it will be easier to explain where your issue is.

What is being returned in the parameter 'res' is an array. Arrays have a access to a method called map. Map takes a function, and will call the function once for each value in the array and overall return a new array with the return values of map.

ie:

```
var res = [{ username: 'jsmith', firstname: 'John' }, { username: 'jdoe', firstname:' Jane" }];

var newArray = res.map(user => user.firstname);
console.log(newArray) // ['John', 'Jane']
```

Based on the mapping function, the first name will be grabbed from each object in the array, and a new array with those values will be created.

Arrays can also be accessed by integer index.
So:

```
var john = res[0];
console.log(john) // { username: 'jsmith', firstname: 'John' }
```

So in your case, you can just do res.map and you would get a each value one by one handed to that callback, and you could process them. Alternatively, you could access the elements by index res[0].id for example.

you can not do res[0].map , because the object stored in the first spot of the response is not an array

Comment: Excellent!  I changed my script to ....let i13 = res.map(res => res.i13); and everything is now being displayed correctly.  The only thing that is left is I receive an error in my terminal "error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'."  But that doesn't stop the data from moving where it needs to go, looks like some kind of syntax error.  Thank you for your help on this! I was chasing my tail around in circles.

Comment: Its probably from a different line in the code. Its definitely calling .map on something that isn't an array. You could try a console.log before every map, and make sure that thing is an array not just an object. I'd probably try to track that down if you have time :) JavaScript wont behave very stable after an error like that. Best of luck.